# Trouble subtracting time from a moment

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I am working on a project that uses a different timezone than the one I currently live in:

`moment.tz.add("Asia/Seoul|LMT KST JST KST KDT KDT|-8r.Q -8u -90 -90 -9u -a0|0123141414141414135353|-2um8r.Q 97XV.Q 1m1zu kKo0 2I0u OL0 1FB0 Rb0 1qN0 TX0 1tB0 TX0 1tB0 TX0 1tB0 TX0 2ap0 12FBu 11A0 1o00 11A0|23e6")`

Then formatted it as such: 
`const kST = moment().tz('Asia/Seoul').format("HH:mm");`

Now I want to be able to subtract a year from that. Looking at examples of how to do that I found something like `var foo = moment(blah, "HH:mm).subtract(1, "years")`

I assumed that since I already defined the moment with the 'const kST' I could simply substitute "kST" for "moment" as such:

`const firstTimeConverted = kST(firstBus, "HH:mm").subtract(1, "years");`

Unfortunately that doesn't work. Any thoughts how I might do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `kST` isn't a function - it's a *string*.  The `format` returns a string formatted as specified.

You probably want:

```
const firstTimeConverted = moment.tz(firstBus, "HH:mm", `Asia/Seoul`).subtract(1, "years");
```

This will parse the string in your `firstBus` variable in `HH:mm` format (such as `"23:45"`), and interpret as belonging to the `Asia/Seoul` time zone on the current date there.  Then it will subtract a year and return the result as a `moment` object.   If you want a string, you would then need to call the `format` function.